# Adding observers to AVPlayerItem

Tags: avplayer, observers

I am working in an app that plays an audio streaming. I have added the observers:playbackBufferEmpty and playbackLikelyToKeepUp to implement a "buffering" message when internet connection is lost.
This is what happens with the following code:  it starts playing without problem, I see the "good to go" message, if I lost the connection it detect the playbackBufferEmpty, I see the "buffering" message, but when the connection is back is like the observer is lost and it doesn't even run observeValueForKeyPath method  with the playbackLikelyToKeepUp.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    …
    NSString *urlstr = @"http://xxxxxxx.aac";
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url]retain];

    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackBufferEmpty" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {



   if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"]){



        if (playerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) {

        escuchando.text = @"buffering";


    }
}

else if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
{
    if (playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
    {

        escuchando.text = @"good to go";

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!